# How to add character limit using listener in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, maxlength

How to add character limit or restrict max length of the text field in flutter without using onchange attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `maxLength` property of the `TextField` to limit the length of the text without using `onChanged()`:

```
TextField(
  maxLength:10
  decoration: InputDecoration(
     counterText: '' //hides the counterText on the bottom of the TextField
  ),
),
```

The above will set your `TextField's` `maxLength` to 10. Here is the documentation for [maxLength](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLength.html)

Comment: Yeah but is there a way to limit the length of the textfield using Listeners? i want to implement this on zefyrfield.

Comment: you would have to use onChanged to limit it. onChanged would listen for any changes on the textfield and execute your code. A listener is basically onChanged since you would have to listen for any changes on your textfield.

Comment: but zefyrfield doesn't seem to have any onChanged property. https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr

Comment: it uses onChanged under the hood. A listener acts exactly like onChanged. I'm not sure why you would want a listener but you could validate the TextFormField when the user clicks submit: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

Comment: I'm trying to add character limit to zefyrfield which does not have attributes like `maxLength` , `onChanged`

Comment: you should've specified that you are trying to add character limit for zefyrfield. You would have to add it yourself. You need to edit the package.